# Sympy: Functional recurrence relations

Tags: python, sympy

I have a function that satisfy several recurrence relations and I am trying to make a sympy program to calculate the successive application of these relations to my function.

As an example, lets say I have two operators O1, and O2 and a function f(x). Now let say that O1*f<sub>i</sub>(x) = (i-2) f<sub>i-1</sub>(x) and O2*f<sub>i</sub>(x) = i*f<sub>i+2</sub>(x).

I would like to symbolically calculate expressions like O1<sup>n<sub>1</sub></sup>  O2<sup>n<sub>2</sub></sup>  f(x).

Comment: By symbolically do you mean n1 and n2 are symbolic variables? For that, you need `rsolve`. If they are explicit numbers I would just write a recursive Python function that computes it.

Comment: No, n1 and n2 should be able to take whatever value I want them to take and the program should return a symbolic expression. I am not after a function value, but the expression for the value. In any case, I found a solution using regex.